# Scapy `sr1` not Responding outside Internal Network

Tags: python, network-programming, scapy

Python: 3.11.4. Scapy: 2.5.0

I'm using Scapy under Windows 10. I created an ICMP packet (with the address of a device in my internal network) and sent it:

```
pkt = IP(dst="10.0.0.254")/ICMP()/Raw("Hello")
rsp = sr1(pkt)
```

The response was received and everything was Okay:

```
Begin emission:
Finished sending 1 packets.
...*
Received 4 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
```

But when I changed the IP address to a device outside my internal network:

```
pkt["IP"].dst = "172.217.22.36"
rsp = sr1(pkt)
```

The output was not what I expected:

```
Begin emission:
Finished sending 1 packets.
........................
Received 2398 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets
```

I sniffed the traffic using Wireshark and discovered that the ICMP request packet includes "No response found!".

The interface in `conf.iface` is the correct interface. I red through FAQs and other questions, but didn't find any solution.